# Struct Array printed the last element

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I wanted to print all the entered elements in the input. But, the code printed the most recently entered one. I expected the program to print every input entered into the Struct arrays. I tried switching to gets and fgets, the output still showing me the same result. Therefore, I couldn't figure out how to make the program print all the given input from the users.

Below is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1
struct Number
{
    char name[100];
};
void read(struct Number *data);
void show(struct Number *data);

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    struct Number data[MAX];
    int option; 

printf("Choose 1 to Read data or Choose 2 to Show Data");
do
    { printf(" \nChoose ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

if(option==1)
    {
    read(data);
    }
else if(option==2)
 {
    show(data);
 }
else 
    {
        printf("Error! \n");
    }
}
while(1);
}
    
 

void show(struct Number *data)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", data[i].name);
    }
}
void read(struct Number *data)
{
        int j;
    for (j=0; j<MAX; j++)
    {
      printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", data[j].name);
    }
}
```

Below is my output:

```
Choose 1 to Read data or Choose 2 to Show Data 
Choose 1
Name: ted   
 
Choose 1
Name: alex
 
Choose 2
alex
```

Thanks everyone! Much appreciated

Comment: `#define MAX 1` and `struct Number data[MAX];` limits you to 1-element in your array... You should really use a separate counter to track the number of names actually entered. That way if less than `MAX` are entered, you don't try and display `MAX` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to your questions is you have defined `#define MAX 1`, so there is only 1-element in your array of struct `struct Number data[MAX];` which means you can only read one name.

Beyond that you have a number of areas where you are having trouble. When taking user-input, you cannot do it correctly unless you ***check the return*** of the input function to determine if input succeeded or failed. You will have a problem reading names with `scanf("%s", ...` because the `"%s"` format specifier stops reading on the first whitespace encountered. That means you will never be able to read `"Siam C."` as the name.

Rather then use `scanf()` for user input, it is recommended that you use `fgets()` so you consume an entire line of input each time. That way, what remains in `stdin` unread does not depend on the `scanf()` format specifier and whether a *matching failure* has occurred. Using `fgets()` to read the entire line, you can then use `sscanf()` to extract any needed numeric values from the line. Then in the case of a *matching failure*, nothing is left in `stdin` to break your next attempted read.

When displaying a menu, make it readable in your code. Unless you are converting a number for output, there is no need for `printf()` a simple `puts()` (or `fputs()` if end-of-line control is needed) will do, e.g.

```
    while (1) { /* loop continually */
        /* make your menu readable */
        fputs ("\nPress 'Enter' on a blank line when done\n\n"
                " 1) Read data\n"
                " 2) Show Data\n\n"
                "Choice: ", stdout);
```

When you have to determine which branch to take based on multiple input values, consider using a `switch()` statement instead of a long chain of `if ... else if ... else`. It functions the same, but provides a more structured approach, e.g.

```
        /* use a switch to control */
        switch (option) {
            case 1:     read (data, &nelem); break;
            case 2:     show (data, nelem); break;
            default:    fputs ("error: invalid choice.\n", stderr); break;
        }
```

As noted above in my comment, you need to keep a separate counter that tracks the number of structs filled. Pass it as a parameter to your `show()` function so you know how many structs to display (also check if it is zero and display `"empty-list"` or similar).

For your `read()` function, you can either pass a pointer to the counter and update the counter within your `read()` function so that then updated count is available back in `main()`, or, you can return the number read and add that to the count kept back in `main()`. (either way is fine, but passing a pointer is a bit more convenient) For example, your `read()` function could be:

```
/* update the number of elements filled through the nelem pointer */
void read (struct Number *data, size_t *nelem)
{
    putchar ('\n');                                     /* newline separator */
    
    while (*nelem < MAX) {                              /* check array not full */
        char *p = data[*nelem].name;                    /* pointer to cut down typing */
        
        fputs ("enter name: ", stdout);                 /* read with fgets() */
        if (!fgets (p, MAX, stdin) || *p == '\n')       /* check return & blank line */
            break;
        p[strcspn (p, "\n")] = 0;                       /* trim '\n' from end of name */
        
        (*nelem)++;                                     /* increment name count */
    }
}
```

(**note:** when you are done entering names, simply press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a blank line -- another benefit using `fgets()` for input. Also note the use of `strcspn()` to trim the `'\n'` included by `fgets()` from the end of each name. This is the easiest and most robust approach.)

Your `show()` function can be:

```
/* pass the number of filled struct as parameter */
void show (struct Number *data, size_t nelem)
{
    size_t i;
    
    putchar ('\n');                                     /* newline separator */
    
    if (nelem == 0) {                                   /* check if list is empty */
        puts ("  (list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)                         /* output all names */
        printf("  Name:  %s\n", data[i].name);
}
```

Putting it altogether you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

struct Number {
    char name[MAX];
};

/* pass the number of filled struct as parameter */
void show (struct Number *data, size_t nelem)
{
    size_t i;
    
    putchar ('\n');                                     /* newline separator */
    
    if (nelem == 0) {                                   /* check if list is empty */
        puts ("  (list-empty)");
        return;
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < nelem; i++)                         /* output all names */
        printf("  Name:  %s\n", data[i].name);
}

/* update the number of elements filled through the nelem pointer */
void read (struct Number *data, size_t *nelem)
{
    putchar ('\n');                                     /* newline separator */
    
    while (*nelem < MAX) {                              /* check array not full */
        char *p = data[*nelem].name;                    /* pointer to cut down typing */
        
        fputs ("enter name: ", stdout);                 /* read with fgets() */
        if (!fgets (p, MAX, stdin) || *p == '\n')       /* check return & blank line */
            break;
        p[strcspn (p, "\n")] = 0;                       /* trim '\n' from end of name */
        
        (*nelem)++;                                     /* increment name count */
    }
}

int main (void) {
    
    char line[MAX];                     /* buffer to hold line of input */
    struct Number data[MAX] = {{""}};   /* initialize all name to empty-string */
    size_t nelem = 0;                   /* number of filled struct */
    int option;
    
    while (1) { /* loop continually */
        /* make your menu readable */
        fputs ("\nPress 'Enter' on a blank line when done\n\n"
                " 1) Read data\n"
                " 2) Show Data\n\n"
                "Choice: ", stdout);
        
        /* read entire line of input into line, break on EOF or blank line */
        if (fgets (line, MAX, stdin) == NULL || *line == '\n')
            break;
        
        /* parse integer from line */
        if (sscanf (line, "%d", &option) != 1) {
            fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }
        
        /* use a switch to control */
        switch (option) {
            case 1:     read (data, &nelem); break;
            case 2:     show (data, nelem); break;
            default:    fputs ("error: invalid choice.\n", stderr); break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Now you can use your menu to add any number of names at a time, `show()` the names, add more names, etc.. up to a `MAX` number of entries:

```
$ ./bin/structnumber

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: 2

  (list-empty)

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: 1

enter name: Mickey Mouse
enter name: Minnie Mouse
enter name:

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: 2

  Name:  Mickey Mouse
  Name:  Minnie Mouse

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: 1

enter name: Donald Duck
enter name: Pluto (the dog)
enter name:

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: 2

  Name:  Mickey Mouse
  Name:  Minnie Mouse
  Name:  Donald Duck
  Name:  Pluto (the dog)

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice:
```

Invalid input is now handled properly:

```
$ ./bin/structnumber

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice: banannas
  error: invalid integer input.

Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done

 1) Read data
 2) Show Data

Choice:
```

(**note:** you can move `"Press 'Enter' on a blank line when done"` out of the loop so it is only shown once -- it was intentionally repeated to remind the user how to end data or menu entries)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.